# ''geometry::Point' failed because parameter 1 is not allowed to be null.' error when converting latlng to GEOM Point

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying simply to convert Lat and Long Coordinates of Taxis to Geometry Points but when I do my query I get this error: ''geometry::Point' failed because parameter 1 is not allowed to be null.'
The statement has been terminated.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[pdPoints] 
 SET  puGeom = GEOMETRY::Point(begintrip_lng, begintrip_lat, 4326),
      dfGeom = GEOMETRY::Point(dropoff_lng, dropoff_lat, 4326)
```

I have tried adding a this statement

```
WHERE 
    begintrip_lng is not null 
 or dropoff_lng is not null 
 or begintrip_lat is not null 
 or dropoff_lat is not null 
 or country_id is not null 
 or city_id is not null;
```

but I get the same result. :( Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 2):

You need `and` instead of `or`

```
WHERE 
     begintrip_lng is not null 
 and dropoff_lng is not null 
 and begintrip_lat is not null 
 and dropoff_lat is not null 
 and country_id is not null 
 and city_id is not null;
```

Try this, You will see some rows will still have null, or maybe more.
Any null will break your update.

```
SELECT *
FROM pdPoints
WHERE 
    begintrip_lng is not null 
 or dropoff_lng is not null 
 or begintrip_lat is not null 
 or dropoff_lat is not null 
 or country_id is not null 
 or city_id is not null;
```

Comment: so im trying it right now but can I ask what makes using 'and' work and 'or' not work?

Comment: If any variable is NULL your query will fail. So you need to check all those are not null, that mean `AND`

Comment: but what if a row has 1 null in it? The 'and' statement does not cover that.